# assign private ip to spot instance

Tags: amazon-ec2

I wanted to find out if there is a way to assign private IP when creating a spot instance.  Looks like by default the AWS Console does not let you know that(its available when launching on-demand instance).  But i am trying to figure out if i can assign private IP for spot instance.

my issue is, i have a image with all my work done(app install etc etc..) and when i use the image to fire off a spot instance and try to login to the webpage it is looking for that specific IP and as spot instance cant give me the desired IP things break...

any help is appreciated..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answering my own question.. so maybe someone looking for this can find it helpful

the way to do this thru CLI is use below, First make sure to create an ENI(in which you have to specify subnet, private ip, sg)...once you have a ENI created run the below

ec2-request-spot-instances ami-ID -p 0.04 --key key_name \
--availability-zone us-east-1d \
--instance-type t1.micro -n 1 --type one-time \
--network-attachment eni-dd3889f0:0

just to clear things up with the last flag("--network-attachment eni-dd3889f0:0")
that is the ENI-ID and the :0 is the dev index.  Dev index is the index you wish the interface to occupy (e.g. eth0). For example, using the above command i am assuming i wished it to be eth0.

Not sure why AWS does not support this thru the console, but atleast we have a option with cli..hope it helps someone.

Comment: Thanks, this worked! It seems that it's not absolutely necessary to use a pre-existing ENI. I used JSON cli input with: `"NetworkInterfaces":[{"DeviceIndex":0,"Description":"Fixed IP","PrivateIpAddress":"172.20.0.20","SubnetId":"subnet-abcdef00","Groups":["sg-12345678"],"DeleteOnTermination":true,"AssociatePublicIpAddress":true}]`